# What does this statemement mean in Future class in dart : FutureOr<R> Function(dynamic) onValue

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

```
Future<R> then<R>(FutureOr<R> onValue(T value), {Function onError});
```

Could someone please in simple language explain what this syntax means [ FutureOr Function(dynamic) onValue ]

Answer (score 1):

`FutureOr<R> Function(dynamic) onValue` means:

`onValue` is a `Function` that receives a `dynamic` and can return `Future<R>` or `R`

---

Here is an example to see how you can pass asynchronous or synchronous functions to `then`:

```
Future<int> fetchNumber() async {
  print("fetch number");
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  return 1;
}

String getText(int value) {
  return "one = $value";
}

Future<String> fetchText(int value) async {
  print("fetch text");
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  return "one = $value";
}

void main() {
  Future<int> firstNumber = fetchNumber();
  Future<String> firstNumberText = firstNumber.then(getText);
  firstNumberText.then(print);

  Future<int> secondNumber = fetchNumber();
  Future<String> secondNumberText = secondNumber.then(fetchText);
  secondNumberText.then(print);

  // This is the same but with anonymous function calls:

  Future<int> firstNumber = fetchNumber();
  Future<String> firstNumberText = firstNumber.then((value) {
    return getText(value);
  });
  firstNumberText.then((text) {
    print(text);
  });

  Future<int> secondNumber = fetchNumber();
  Future<String> secondNumberText = secondNumber.then((value) {
    return fetchText(value);
  });
  secondNumberText.then((text) {
    print(text);
  });
}
```

Output:

> I/flutter ( 8169): fetch number
>
> I/flutter ( 8169): fetch number
>
> I/flutter ( 8169): one = 1
>
> I/flutter ( 8169): fetch text
>
> I/flutter ( 8169): one = 1

Comment: this is going to sound a little bit stupid but how is the anonymous function that is passed inside then() invocation get called or who calls it.

Comment: The implementation of `then` could use the function received by parameter like this: `FutureOr<R> result = onValue(data);` in the example I provided it could be something like: `FutureOr<String> text = onValue(number);`. For example, `then` is being called by the future `firstNumber` that knows what data (`int`) to pass to the `onValue` function, and the `onValue` function will receive that data and then it can return a `Future<int>` or an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html) description explains the FutureOr will either return the value you expect or a `Future` that you can `await` on. Take a look at the functions of this example, copy the code and try it yourself:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
 AnimationController _animationController;

 @override
  void initState() {
   _animationController = AnimationController(
     vsync: this,
     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
   );
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stackoverflow playground'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => printString(),
              child: Text('Without await'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => printStringWithAwait(),
              child: Text('With await'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  void printString() {
    String string = newString();
    print('Without await $string');
  }

  void printStringWithAwait() async {
    String string = await newString();
    print('With await $string');
  }

  FutureOr<String> newString(){
    return 'FutureOr';
  }
}
```